# Little bit complex routes in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I would like to achieve a routing as you can see the example below, controllers are missing at the moment.

I like it because the routes reflects how the partials are organized and how the system modules are exists. After a little search it seems angular route can't do this for me.

How can I do this with angular? I would like to avoid using 3rd party stuff. At the moment I have to simplify it and it is not a problem, but it is not that 'beauty' how I like it.

Do you have any information about when angular routing, out of the box, will be able to manage a routing like this? I came across a comment about that in the future this will be implemented, but version it wasn't mentioned.

```js
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/admin/usermanagement', {
            templateUrl: "app/dilib/partials/admin/user_management.html",
        })
        .when('/admin/userrights', {
            templateUrl: "app/dilib/partials/admin/user_rights.html",
        })
        .when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'app/dilib/partials/dashboard/dashboard.html'
        });
```

Comment: I think that should work, you do need to include the route JS file though //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-route.js

Comment: *"After a little search it seems angular route can't do this for me"*. What exactly is not working, your code is fine.

Comment: @dfsq: The content of the user_management.html is not displayed in the `<div ng-view></div>`. If I change the routes something like this `admin_user_management` it is working.

Comment: @RTPMatt: What do you mean? Every file is included, my stuff, angular-route stuff, etc.

Comment: if your app is in app/dilib/ delete this part from the url

Comment: @micha: Where is your answer in which you write that I should add a `/admin` route with a template `<div ng-view></div>`? It works, btw.

Comment: Perhaps you've misspelled the name of the file/location and you recieve an error? Take a look in your dev console. It's hard for us to help you out without know how you've got things structure on your backend. Routewise this looks perfectly fine.

Comment: @mengstrom You are right! I created a very simple example and it works as I expected. I have to check my code again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the root of this problem. The templateUrl paths are not correct. My application is under dev.domain.local/ui/ so the templateUrl must be changed accordingly.

```js
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/ui/admin/usermanagement', {
            templateUrl: "app/dilib/partials/admin/user_management.html",
        })
        .when('/ui/admin/userrights', {
            templateUrl: "app/dilib/partials/admin/user_rights.html",
        })
        .when('/ui/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'app/dilib/partials/dashboard/dashboard.html'
        });
```